# Where to sign in for VS 2013 Express Preview

Tags: visual-studio

I don't know if this question is proper for stackoverflow or for other Stack site, so please migrate it to the correct place:)

I got VS 2013 Express Preview and after 15 days it expired. I have this message:

[image]

Where may I sign in to extend the license? I'm already signed in with my MS account(you can see the Sign out text in the lest). I tried to search on google, but most result are not related to VS 2013(other versions get in the way!). I read some blog posts about this but nothing got me to the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you've already seen this but posting anyway:

Apparently there has been a [bug related to the time zone](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792529/unable-to-update-my-license-for-visual-studio-2013-previeww) that affected the license renewal. It could be that bug that makes it impossible to renew for you. A workaround is apparently to change the time zone to `Pacific Standard Time` before launching VS then changing it back again. This can be done in a command shell with:`tzutil /s "Pacific Standard Time"`.

Hope this helps.